# Switch wireless keyboard/trackpad while using iMac as external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, imac, bluetooth, trackpad

I have an iMac with a pair of wireless keyboard/trackpad and another Macbook Pro (MBP). I just got a thunderbolt cable and try to use iMac as an external monitor for the MBP.

However, one problem is that, I have to press cmd+F2 on iMac. Then after that the wireless keyboard/trackpad will have problem pair with MBP using bluetooth, because it's still paired with iMac.

Is there a better way to have keyboard/trackpad easily switch between my iMac and MBP? I know two of the solutions but none of them seems to be very appealing to me:
1) Buy another pair of keyboard/trackpad just for MBP
2) Logitech got a easy-switch keyboard but no easy-switch trackpad

Any suggestion would be great. Thanks.

Comment: This question is for "wireless" while the duplicate is for "bluetooth" - they're not necessarily the same thing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/).  It's a virtual keyboard/mouse switcher between multiple OS types.  You install the same client on each machine you want to use, and on the "master" machine (server), you configure the virtual arrangement of all the screens.

Very easy to use and set up.  I use it between multiple Macs while they're each booted into their own OS's.  The keyboard/mouse stays "connected" to the "server," so here's how you might use it for your problem:

1. Download and install Synergy on both machines.
2. Setup the iMac as the "client."
3. Setup the MacBook Pro as the "server."
4. Drag the mouse cursor to the iMac and press Command+F2.

I haven't tested this exact setup myself, but I think it might be a feasable solution.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the original answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23146/sharing-a-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-sequentially-between-two-macs/207281#207281), because that question is older and more popular. I think more people will find it there. But I leave here some highlights.

> There's [VirtualKVM](https://github.com/duanefields/VirtualKVM/releases) software solution by Duane Fields, which perfectly suites your needs.

You can download it [here](https://github.com/duanefields/VirtualKVM/releases) and read [the full answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23146/sharing-a-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-sequentially-between-two-macs/207281#207281) if you need details about how does it work.

Comment: re the first line the correct way is to flag or close this question as a duplicate of the other