# Switching bluetooth device between two Macbook Pros

Tags: keyboard, mojave, catalina, bluetooth, mouse

I have two different MacBook pros (`Catalina` and `Mojave`). Recently, I bought a new bluetooth mice and a keyboard. First time, when I connected keyboard and mice to one of the MacBook Pros, I had to turn off/on the bluetooth devices and then was able to connect to one of the MacBook Pro. When I had to connect to my second MacBook Pro I did the same.

The most annoying part to me here is when I try to switch these devices to connect to one of the Mac's I have to do the same thing which is turn off/on mice and keyboard every single time and then pair/connect.

I definitely think that there must be a better way to do it, can someone please help?

Like AirPods can I just connect automatically every time when I turn on one of the mac's?

Better solution than this? [Sharing a Bluetooth Keyboard and Mouse sequentially between two Macs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23146/sharing-a-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse-sequentially-between-two-macs?rq=1)